# Keep only one line per date when doing get_dummy in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame like this

```
Item  Value  Date
A      30    01/01/2010
A      50    01/02/2010
A      70    01/03/2010
A      50    01/04/2010
B      10    01/01/2010
B      15    01/02/2010
B      23    01/03/2010
B      11    01/04/2010
```

And I would like to convert it to a dataframe looking like this

```
Date         A    B
01/01/2010   30   10
01/02/2010   50   15
01/03/2010   70   23
01/04/2010   50   11
```

Keeping one line per date with all the information of each item, how can I do that?

Comment: can you be sure that there will be exactly one A and one B value for each date?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.pivot(index="Date", columns="Item", values="Value")
```

Arguments used:

- `index`: column used as new index
- `columns`: column used to set new dataframe columns
- `values`: values in the new columns

*output*

```
# Item         A   B
# Date
# 01/01/2010  30  10
# 01/02/2010  50  15
# 01/03/2010  70  23
# 01/04/2010  50  11
```

For much more details about this kind of transformation, see [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Equivalent `groupby`, but a little longer: `df.groupby(['Date', 'Item'])['Value'].first().unstack()`